# CSP settings for separate js file

Tags: apache, content-security-policy, script-src

Does `script-src` parameter using hashes works for inline scripts only?

This config works for for me (inline script in HTML code):

Apache config:

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: "script-src  'sha256-U82JgRvGjy4mzia+G8DutvX8V/W33LIoO2UuwT+rE/0='"
```

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Hello!</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <p>This is a simple paragraph.</p>
    </body>

    <script>alert('hello everybody')</script>

</html>
```

where:
`U82JgRvGjy4mzia+G8DutvX8V/W33LIoO2UuwT+rE/0=` is a sha256 hash code of
`alert('hello everybody')` converted into base64

Once I moved the same script `alert('hello everybody')` into separate js file test.js and have updated index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Hello!</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <p>This is a simple paragraph.</p>
    </body>

    <script src="test.js"></script>

</html>
```

CSP blocking test.js file, however hash for it still the same

> [Report Only] Refused to load the script 'http://localhost/test.js'
> because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
> "script-src 'sha256-U82JgRvGjy4mzia+G8DutvX8V/W33LIoO2UuwT+rE/0='".
> Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is
> used as a fallback.

What parameter should I use for CSP to allow local js file by hash?

Answer (score 0):

This should allow loading a script from the same source: "script-src 'self';"

Comment: you are right, 'self' parameter allows to run all local scripts from the host. But I need to allow it by hash, to avoid script changes before running.

Comment: You can do so in CSP level 3, see https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#external-hash. But it may not have full browser support yet. This could also be done with Subresource Integrity: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity